# aspectj - AND and OR in the same pointcut

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-aop, aspect

I'd like to do something when `getAll(...)` or `getRec(...)` methods are called in `com.acme.dao.impl.*DaoImpl` classes but exclude the `com.acme.dao.impl.*ViewDaoImpl` classes.

I can do the 1st requirement with

```
execution(* com.acme.dao.impl.*DaoImpl.getAll(..)) || execution(* com.acme.dao.impl.*DaoImpl.getNRecs(..))
```

but not sure how to exclude the *ViewDaoImpl classes.
I presume I should do something like

```
!execution(* com.acme.dao.impl.*ViewDaoImpl.*(..))
```

but how to add to the include expression?

Thanks,
V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options. The one closest to what you already have is:

```java
(execution(* com.acme.dao.impl.*DaoImpl.getAll(..)) || execution(* com.acme.dao.impl.*DaoImpl.getNRecs(..))) &&
!execution(* com.acme.dao.impl.*ViewDaoImpl.*(..))
```

But you can also use this, I think it is a bit more readable:

```java
within(com.acme.dao.impl.*DaoImpl) && !within(*..*ViewDaoImpl) &&
(execution(* getAll(..)) || execution(* getNRecs(..)))
```

Assuming that all DAO classes would implement the same interface as given above, this would also work (`Dao+` captures all implementing classes and their subclasses):

```java
within(com.acme.dao.impl.Dao+) && !within(*..*ViewDaoImpl) &&
(execution(* getAll(..)) || execution(* getNRecs(..)))
```

Here is a pure AspectJ example, but it should be just the same aspect code for Spring AOP:

**Sample application classes:**

```java
package com.acme.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

public interface Dao {
  List getAll();
  List getNRecs();
  void doSomething();
}
```

```java
package com.acme.dao.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FirstDaoImpl implements Dao {
  @Override
  public List getAll() {
    return new ArrayList();
  }

  @Override
  public List getNRecs() {
    return new ArrayList();
  }

  @Override
  public void doSomething() {}
}
```

```java
package com.acme.dao.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SecondDaoImpl implements Dao {
  @Override
  public List getAll() {
    return new ArrayList();
  }

  @Override
  public List getNRecs() {
    return new ArrayList();
  }

  @Override
  public void doSomething() {}
}
```

```java
package com.acme.dao.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyViewDaoImpl implements Dao {
  @Override
  public List getAll() {
    return new ArrayList();
  }

  @Override
  public List getNRecs() {
    return new ArrayList();
  }

  @Override
  public void doSomething() {}
}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.Arrays;

import com.acme.dao.impl.Dao;
import com.acme.dao.impl.FirstDaoImpl;
import com.acme.dao.impl.MyViewDaoImpl;
import com.acme.dao.impl.SecondDaoImpl;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    for (Class<?> clazz : Arrays.asList(FirstDaoImpl.class, SecondDaoImpl.class, MyViewDaoImpl.class)) {
      Dao dao = (Dao) clazz.newInstance();
      dao.getAll();
      dao.getNRecs();
      dao.doSomething();
    }
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

I have added a lot of line breaks and indentation within the pointcut strings, of course you don't need to do that. It is just for clarity here in this Q/A scenario on StackOverflow.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class DaoAspect {
  @Before(
    "(" + 
      "execution(* com.acme.dao.impl.*DaoImpl.getAll(..)) || " + 
      "execution(* com.acme.dao.impl.*DaoImpl.getNRecs(..))" + 
    ") && " + 
    "!execution(* com.acme.dao.impl.*ViewDaoImpl.*(..))"
  )
  public void firstVariant(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    System.out.println("[1] " + thisJoinPoint);
  }

  @Before(
    "within(com.acme.dao.impl.*DaoImpl) && " +
    "!within(*..*ViewDaoImpl) && " +
    "(" +
      "execution(* getAll(..)) || " +
      "execution(* getNRecs(..))" +
    ")" 
  )
  public void secondVariant(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    System.out.println("[2] " + thisJoinPoint);
  }

  @Before(
    "within(com.acme.dao.impl.Dao+) && " +
    "!within(*..*ViewDaoImpl) && " +
    "(" +
      "execution(* getAll(..)) || " +
      "execution(* getNRecs(..))" +
    ")" 
  )
  public void thirdVariant(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    System.out.println("[3] " + thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
[1] execution(List com.acme.dao.impl.FirstDaoImpl.getAll())
[2] execution(List com.acme.dao.impl.FirstDaoImpl.getAll())
[3] execution(List com.acme.dao.impl.FirstDaoImpl.getAll())
[1] execution(List com.acme.dao.impl.FirstDaoImpl.getNRecs())
[2] execution(List com.acme.dao.impl.FirstDaoImpl.getNRecs())
[3] execution(List com.acme.dao.impl.FirstDaoImpl.getNRecs())
[1] execution(List com.acme.dao.impl.SecondDaoImpl.getAll())
[2] execution(List com.acme.dao.impl.SecondDaoImpl.getAll())
[3] execution(List com.acme.dao.impl.SecondDaoImpl.getAll())
[1] execution(List com.acme.dao.impl.SecondDaoImpl.getNRecs())
[2] execution(List com.acme.dao.impl.SecondDaoImpl.getNRecs())
[3] execution(List com.acme.dao.impl.SecondDaoImpl.getNRecs())
```

As you can see, all three variants do exactly the same. Choose according to your own preference.

Comment: Brilliant! The `within(com.acme.dao.impl.*DaoImpl) && !within(*..*ViewDaoImpl) &&
(execution(* getAll(..)) || execution(* getNRecs(..)))` did the trick! I had to change the && to 'and' but otherwise it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: If you had to change it to 'and', probably you do not define your pointcuts in code but in XML. You should have mentioned that, there was no way of knowing the way you asked your question, showing the pointcut in isolation. Context is important when asking technical (or any kind of) questions. :-)

Comment: @Viktor a nice detailed answer like this might worth an upvote too, besides accepting it ;-)